# How to wait for a dispatch to end before continuing runtime

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm building an app using React Native, and I have the following code

```
sumbit_answer(answer) {
  this.setState({isLoading: true})
  if (this.props.curr_round_correct_answer == '') {
   this.props.dispatch(insert_correct_answer(answer));
    //replace
  } else {
   this.props.dispatch(insert_answer(this.props.current_player, answer));
  }

  if (
    this.props.curr_round_results.length ==
    this.props.players_names.length - 1
  ) {
    this.props.navigation.replace('RoundStatistics');
  } else {
    this.props.navigation.replace('PassPlayer');
  }
}
```

Basically I want to run the second if statement only when the dispatch from the previous if is completed, that is currently not happening. The dispatch does not make any API calls, only changes to the redux state. So how can I prevent this from happening? I though about using the await keyword, but does not feel right.Thanks!!!

Comment: Dispatch returns a promise using redux thunk middleware, so you can use it to wait until it resolve and then do other bit with your code

Comment: More info https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#async-action-creators

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat opinionated answer, but I think the best way to handle this is to move the second section elsewhere and make it conditional based on a combination of local state and selectors.  You can call it within a `useEffect` hook.

You should be able to tell the dispatch has completed and when you are ready for the next step by looking at the redux state.  You can also use local state to store boolean flags like `didSubmitAnswer` if needed.  Somehow you combine that information into an `isCompletedRound` boolean.  Your `useEffect` hook fires the navigation actions if `isCompletedRound === true`.